# How to select with multiple IN conditions on TEMPORARY table?

Tags: mysql

### The Problem

I would like to sanitize a messy database and replace references to duplicate entries. In this custom made (mine is far more complex) example I have two tables:

- Octopuses
- Colors

We know that:

- An octopus **has** a color.
- Table `colors` contain duplicates
- Some octopuses may have the same color as other octopuses, but different `color_id`.

The way I solved this problem involves `TEMPORARY` tables. To avoid the error:

```
Can't Reopen Table 'duplicates'
```

I simply duplicate my `TEMPORARY` table many times:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates1 SELECT * FROM duplicates;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates2 SELECT * FROM duplicates;
```

### The Question

I would like to avoid to clone `TEMPORARY` tables.

### The Data

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`octopuses` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `color_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `test`.`colors` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

With some colors with duplicate:

```
INSERT INTO colors (name) VALUES
    ('cream'), ('sepia'), ('daffodil'), ('lipstick'),                        
    ('lipstick'), ('garnet'), ('flamingo'), ('navy'),                        
    ('chartreuse'), ('garnet'), ('flamingo'), ('juniper'),                             
    ('flint'), ('flint'), ('charcoal'), ('garnet');
```

And some octopuses:

```
INSERT INTO octopuses (name, color_id) VALUES
    ('Bubbles', 1), ('Inky', 8), ('Octavius', 1),
    ('Sir Inks-A-Lot', 7), ('Octavia', 16), ('Kraken', 6),
    ('Oncho', 15), ('Big Floppy Sea Spider', 14), ('Calamari', 2),
    ('Scuba Doo', 13), ('Squidward Tentacles', 5), ('Wiggleton', 9),
    ('Cthulhu', 2), ('Octopussy', 3), ('Triton', 10), 
    ('Doctor Octopus', 11), ('Billy The Squid', 4), ('Stretch', 12);
```

### The Example

To solve the problem I first create the list of duplicates:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates SELECT
    *, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    colors
GROUP BY name
HAVING count > 1;
```

Here it is:

```
mysql> select * FROM duplicates;
+----+----------+-------+
| id | name     | count |
+----+----------+-------+
|  4 | lipstick |     2 |
|  6 | garnet   |     3 |
|  7 | flamingo |     2 |
| 13 | flint    |     2 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

Then I would like to create a corresponding table where I have the `id` of a duplicate and the `id` to be replaced with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates1 SELECT * FROM duplicates;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE duplicates2 SELECT * FROM duplicates;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE corresponding SELECT
    id, name,
    (SELECT
            id
        FROM
            duplicates2
        WHERE
            duplicates2.name = colors.name) AS first_id
FROM
    colors
WHERE
    name IN (SELECT
            name
        FROM
            duplicates)
        AND id NOT IN (SELECT
            id
        FROM
            duplicates1)
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Here the content:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM corresponding;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | name     | first_id |
+----+----------+----------+
| 11 | flamingo |        7 |
| 14 | flint    |       13 |
| 10 | garnet   |        6 |
| 16 | garnet   |        6 |
|  5 | lipstick |        4 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Then I simply update the `octopuses` table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE corresponding1 SELECT * FROM corresponding;

UPDATE octopuses
SET
    color_id = (SELECT
            first_id
        FROM
            corresponding1
        WHERE
            corresponding1.id = color_id)
WHERE
    color_id IN (SELECT
            id
        FROM
            corresponding)
```

Eventually I remove the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM colors WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM corresponding);
```

### The Summary

This example is perhaps not the best to illustrate my issue, but here I would like to avoid to clone temporary tables and find a way to select with multiple `IN` conditions on `TEMPORARY` tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to think the other way around.

You could do:

```
UPDATE octopuses
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *,
            (SELECT 
                    id
                FROM
                    colors
                WHERE
                    colors.name = (SELECT 
                            name
                        FROM
                            colors
                        WHERE
                            color_id = colors.id)
                LIMIT 1) AS first_color_id
    FROM
        octopuses
    HAVING color_id <> first_color_id) AS DUP ON dup.color_id = octopuses.color_id 
SET 
    octopuses.color_id = first_color_id
WHERE
    octopuses.color_id <> first_color_id;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to_delete SELECT id FROM colors WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM octopuses WHERE color_id = colors.id
);

DELETE FROM colors WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM to_delete);
```

So the answer to your question is:

> Whenever you need to clone a temporary table, think twice and you will find another way that do no involve reopening temporary table twice!